# GEE Python API - Why does this function not map over a collection?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I have made a function to add an `isNull:False` and the mean values of each band as properties to an image, or `isNull: True` if the image contains no data. I want to use the function to map over an image collection.

A reproducible example:

```py
import ee
ee.Initialize()

def cloudmask_LS(image):
    cloudAdjacentBitMask = (1 << 3)
    cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 2)
    cloudsBitMask = (1 << 1)
    ## get the pixel QA band.
    qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL') 
    mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0).And(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0)).And(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudAdjacentBitMask).eq(0))
    return image.updateMask(mask)

aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([10.02244,2.27462, 10.06668,2.26841, 10.06869,2.23237, 10.01983,2.23518])

start_date =  "2018-01-01"
end_date =  "2021-12-31"
l7 = (ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2")
        .filterDate(ee.Date(start_date), ee.Date(end_date))
        .filterBounds(aoi)
        .map(lambda image: image.clip(aoi))
    )

## band names
band_names = ['SR_B1', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B7', 'QA_PIXEL']

## cloud mask collection
l7 = l7.select(band_names).map(cloudmask_LS)

## drop QA_PIXEL band
band_names = [b for b in band_names if not b == 'QA_PIXEL']
l7 = l7.select(band_names)

def get_band_means(image):
    ## get means of bands in a dictionary
    meanDict = image.reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry=aoi, scale=30)
    
    ## convert to Python dict
    means = meanDict.getInfo()
    
    ## if mean values missing, set isNull to True
    if None in means.values():
        isNull = True
    else:
        isNull = False
    
    ## add a key, value pair to the means dict indicating whether image is null
    means['isNull'] = isNull
    
    ## add the means dictionary to the image as properties
    return image.set(means)
    
l7 = l7.map(get_band_means)
```

Throws the error:

> ee.ee_exception.EEException: ValueNode is empty

and a little further up the error message

> with_cast = lambda e: algorithm(element_type(e)) 
> File "< string >", line 39, in get_band_means

which is the line `means = meanDict.getInfo()`

However, when I choose a null image and manually perform the operations, it works as expected.

```py
l7_list = l7.toList(len(l7.getInfo()['features']))

## a null image was found by visual inspection
null_image = ee.Image(l7_list.get(4))

## get means of bands in a dictionary
meanDict = null_image.reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry=aoi, scale=30)

## convert to Python dict
means = meanDict.getInfo()

## if mean values missing, set isNull to True
if None in means.values():
    isNull = True
else:
    isNull = False

## add a key, value pair to the means dict indicating whether image is null
means['isNull'] = isNull

## add the means dictionary to the image as properties
null_image = null_image.set(means)

null_image.getInfo()['properties']
```

Note the `isNull` property is added as desired.

> {'system:footprint': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [...]}, 'isNull': True,  ... }

To verify the mean values were added as properties, I chose a non-null image and repeated the operations manually. The properties were successfully added.

```py
nonNull_image = ee.Image(l7_list.get(70))
```

> {'system:footprint': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [...]}, 'SR_B1': 8933.524251313218, 'isNull': False, 'SR_B2': 9380.560890927749, 'SR_B3': 8928.16497726643, 'SR_B4': 17325.19809467158, 'SR_B5': 11964.02872713739, 'SR_B7': 9085.548239710133,

Comment: You can't use `.getInfo()` in the function you pass to `ee.ImageCollection.map()`. The result of `.getInfo()` is a client-side object, which can't get back to EE servers in a `.map` expression. You can do `ee.ImageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.notNull())` on the reduction properties to get rid of images that had a null reduction.

Comment: Thank you, @JustinBraaten. That makes a lot of sense. The body of the entire working function is essentially just `return image.set(image.reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry=aoi, scale=30))`. If you would like to promote your comment to an answer, I can accept it as correct.

Comment: Great to hear that worked, I've moved the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `.getInfo()` in the function you pass to `ee.ImageCollection.map()`. The result of `.getInfo()` is a client-side object, which can't get back to EE servers in a `.map` expression. You can do `ee.ImageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.notNull())` on the reduction properties to get rid of images that had a null reduction.

Basically your `get_band_means` function would be this:

```py
def get_band_means(image):
    ## get means of bands in a dictionary
    meanDict = image.reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry=aoi, scale=30)
    
    ## add the means dictionary to the image as properties
    return image.set(meanDict)
```

...and then to remove any images that had null reductions, do this:

```py
l7_with_data = l7.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(band_names))
```

When you compare the collection size, original has 121 images and after filtering out the null reduction images there are 80.

*If you need to know what images were filtered out, you can probably get that info with a join on the pre- and post-null-filtered collections (submit a separate question).*